# Is asking to translate a short paragraph from English to French on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I want to see if I'm allowed to ask such a question in the main site?

> Would you please translate the following paragraphs into French?
>
> - a proposal for creating a remote sensing and photogrammeetry Q&A site    in StackExchange Network is in commitment phase now
> - All the instructions you need to know to be an effective committer to    the remote sensing and photogrammetry proposal in StackExchange
> - You can also have a look at the homepage and the "definition phase is    over!" page of this google site.
> - There I've summarized all the efforts from last year and also have    linked  to valuable tutorials which introduce the StackExchange
>     network and make you more familiar with what I'm trying to do
> - Let's make a website for remote sensing and photogrammetry real.    Let's all press "commit" button!
>
> I need them to post about [this proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/90327/remote-sensing-and-photogrammetry?referrer=8G2asYAyI_To9RoVf1VtPg2) in facebook pages that
>   are related to the topic and promote it. Because as you know and as
>   facebook suggests, posts in local languages receive more likes and
>   more attention and so they might be seen by more people.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Translation in general is off-topic on *French Language*. This is mentioned in the [help sections](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> **What about translations?** We are not a translation service, nor do we purport to be experts in languages other than French. Asking about the meaning of a difficult French sentence is fine. So is asking how to express an idea in idiomatic French. But please don't ask us to translate a text to or from another language.

However, you are welcome on the *French Language* chat *[Chez Cosette](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/chez-cosette)*. You will likely find people there who will be glad to provide some help.

Comment: thanks for your advice